# How to handle extremely long convolutional sequence memory size in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, gpu

I believe this is a unique problem, but definitely link me to other answers elsewhere if they exist. I have a convolutional sequential network in Keras, very similar to the one in the [guide to the sequential model (and here is their model):](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, MaxPooling1D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(seq_length, 100)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=16)
```

Unfortunately, my sequence sizes are pretty massive (up to a million), and I would really like to do an embedding. With that, I'd like to do 2d Convolution (and possibly much deeper architectures). My GPU runs fast enough as convolution is easy, but it has 2GB of memory. Therefore, I cannot even train the network one sample at a time. As soon as I introduce an embedding, it will explode the size of the network - in this example, (batch_size, 1000000, 100, embed_size).

I know about [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), but using fit_generator (and TimeSeriesGenerator) requires me to have a label for every step of the broken up timesteps of the sequence. My problem is a simple classification problem so it does not make sense to provide a label at, for example, after the first 1000 timesteps of the sequence compared to all million. My impression is that the network is probably running the GlobalAveragePooling for every part of the broken up sequence. As proof, when I run fit_generator compared to regular_fit on a small dataset, the performance for fit_generator suffers greatly.

Therefore my problem is: what can I use to create a large network to run on extremely long sequences in Keras? Is it possible I am misunderstanding fit_generator? Or is there some other way to break up long sequences into parts? If this absolutely does not exist, I can probably write it myself and submit it to Keras, but I would rather not.

This is NOT like an LSTM with extremely long sequence lengths because I do not care about TBTT, and convolutional networks do not have state.

Comment: interesting, if one sample is not going to fit in memory fit_generator isn't going to work. So no you're not mistaken about fit_generator. I pulled you model in and as it stands has 105,729 trainable parameters. That ~ 0.008 gbs if you use 32 bit floats - training the model shouldn't be a problem.  I didnt however run out of memory trying to simulate an x_train with` np.random,randn(100, 1000000, 100)`  so then I tried `np.random.rand(1, 1000000, 100)` and I could fit that in memory. Have you _tried_ a single example?

Comment: @putonspectacles yes, I have tried the model. Apologies, the model shown was just the example from documentation to keep the question short. My issue comes in when specifically when I try to do an embedding as the first layer as this will increase the size to, for example, (1, 1000000, 100, embed_size). Even doing an embedding of size 2 does not work for me. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: ahhhh, do you need to _all_ the elements from the sequence? I.e since this is a classification task, you might consider that there could be for instance redundancy in the sequence

Comment: Could you please explain what your data is? As I see, a sequence (of up to one million) of vectors of 100 dimensions. That doesn't make sense to me to pass to an embedding, as it needs indexes. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @putonspectacles  All elements of the sequence are necessary, most likely... although I will investigate. That's an interesting thought. However, I doubt many of the vectors are the same, read my next comment

Comment: @AbderrahimKitouni It is a sequence of sentences, where each sentence is 100 words long (padded). Therefore an embedding will create a matrix of the sentence (as I understand embeddings) and the problem becomes a sequence of matrices.

Comment: I think you'll be able to increase the batch size if you "siamese" and concatenate before `avg_pool`, but I'm still a little confused: what shape do you expect the output to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this, to solve the issue I simply used a max pooling layer (not avg. pooling) of size 10 as the input. This effectively reduces the number of items in the sequence by a factor of 10, allowing space for the embedding layer.

It performs great, so I don't think reducing the input had an adverse affect. Using Max pooling essentially just chooses items at random, as the number values for each item are chosen at random.

Answer (score 2):

You have a sequence of sentences, and the embedding can only be applied to one sentence at a time, so you need to wrap it in a TimeDistributed layer

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, TimeDistributed

# plug-in your own values
vocab_size = 10000
embed_size = 200
seq_length = 1000000

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size),
          input_shape=(seq_length, 100)))
```

The above gives me an input_shape of `(None, 1000000, 100)` and an output shape of `(None, 1000000, 100, 200)`, with 2 million parameters.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That makes sense. However, running this it still contributes to my original problem that the matrix cannot fit in my memory.